# I want to rewrite an URL on my site... What can I do?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL, `www.example.com/(language)/contact` into `www.example.com/con.htm?lang=(language)`, so what should I use?

Comment: If you add answers, I will probably validate them if pertinent; it's a Wiki Q&A!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check that you, on the distant server, have access to a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of the server.

Now, you first need to type

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in order for the rewrite to work.

Now, you can use the magical `RewriteRule` token. What is it? A rewrite rule.

Now the way it works is pretty simple: The URL typed in is to be typed just next to `RewriteRule`, with `(.*)` representing your variable, here `(language)`. The output URL which is the URL to be crawled by the server is just after, and the content of the variable `(.*)` we talked about above will be placed where `$1` is.

Giving us:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)/contact /con.htm?lang=$1
```

as the content of `.htaccess` for what you asked.

Input:

```
www.example.com/fr/contact
```

Output:

```
www.example.com/con.htm?lang=fr
```

And it works everytime!

Also you can add as many `RewriteRule`s as you want!

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks` is not needed; it configures something complete unrelated

Comment: @Sjon ah okay, I thought it was part of it. So I'm gonna edit away!