# Getting doxia-module-markdown to rewrite *.md links

Tags: markdown, maven-site-plugin, doxia

My goal is to generate site documentation that is also browsable from within github, so I've written a bunch of markdown pages.

I'm using `maven-site-plugin` with `doxia-module-markdown` to generate project documentation.

The problem I'm running into is that links of the form `[foo](foo.md)` show up in the generated HTML as `<a href="foo.md">foo</a>`, not `<a href="foo.html">foo</a>`.

Changing the link to point to `foo.html` would make things unbrowseable from Github, and it seems to me that the `.md`→`.html` mapping is integral to how the HTML generation works, so link rewriting should be happening here.

Below is a minimal case to repro which produces the following output for me

Am I missing some configuration option to get relative link rewriting to also apply the source file path to target file path translation?

The translated HTML contains .md links.

```
$ mvn clean site && cat target/site/a.html | grep -i banana
...
<p>&#x2018;A&#x2019; is for apple, <a href="b.md">&#x2018;b&#x2019;</a> is for banana.</p>
```

---

### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Foo</name>
  <description>
  Tests link rewriting using the doxia markdown module.
  </description>
  <url>https://example.com/</url>  <!-- should not affect relative URLs -->

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

### site.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project>
  <skin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
  </skin>

  <body>
    <links>
    </links>

    <menu name="docs">
      <item name="a" href="a.html"/>
      <item name="b" href="b.html"/>
    </menu>

    <menu ref="reports"/>

    <menu ref="modules"/>

    <menu ref="parent"/>
  </body>
</project>
```

---

### a.md

```md
# A

'A' is for apple, ['b'](b.md) is for banana.
```

---

### b.md

```md
# B

['A'](a.md) is for apple, 'b' is for banana.
```

Answer (score 3):

[`markdown-page-generator-plugin`](https://github.com/walokra/markdown-page-generator-plugin) provides a `transformRelativeMarkdownLinks` option which will transform relative url suffix from ".md" to ".html" if option true. (Default: false.)

#### Setup:

- Put markdown files to be processed by `doxia-module-markdown` in `/src/site/markdown/`
- Put markdown files to be processed by `markdown-page-generator-plugin` in a differently named folder such as `/src/site/markdown_/`
- Put html code added by `doxia-module-markdown` into `header.html` and `footer.html`
- Configure `markdown-page-generator-plugin` to include `header.html` and `footer.html`
- Configure `markdown-page-generator-plugin` to add processed file to the same target folder used  by `doxia-module-markdown`

#### Adapt `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- processes ${project.basedir}/src/site/markdown/ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
      <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.ruleoftech</groupId>
  <artifactId>markdown-page-generator-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <inputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/site/markdown_/</inputDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/</outputDirectory>

    <!-- copy other /markdown_/* directories -->
    <copyDirectories>images_,quickstart_files</copyDirectories>

    <!-- put doxia-module-markdown additional html in these header & footer files -->
    <headerHtmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/site/markdown_/html/header.html</headerHtmlFile>
    <footerHtmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/site/markdown_/html/footer.html</footerHtmlFile>

    <!-- transform relative url suffix from ".md" to ".html" -->
    <transformRelativeMarkdownLinks>true</transformRelativeMarkdownLinks>

    <pegdownExtensions>ANCHORLINKS,HARDWRAPS,AUTOLINKS,TABLES,FENCED_CODE_BLOCKS</pegdownExtensions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

#### Update:

The Apache Maven Doxia Markdown Module 1.8 was updated to ["switch parser from Pegdown to Flexmark"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DOXIA-554). So, markdown generator used in groupId com.ruleoftech, artifactId markdown-page-generator-plugin is now part of the Maven Doxia itself.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
  <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

*Caveat: Although Maven Doxia 1.8 uses [flex-markjava](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java), it is not certain that all of the `flexmark-java` features are made available via Doxia. The `markdown-page-generator-plugin` does remain an option for working with markdown content outside the context of Doxia, if Doxia is not surfacing the desired `flexmark-java` features.*

Comment: @l-marc-l Thank you for you answer. After the update of doxia-module-markdown to use flexmark in version 1.8, is the use of markdown-page-generator-plugin still necessary to rewrite the links from .md to .html? Thank you!

Comment: @jmones Maven Doxia 1.8 uses `flexmark-java`, thus `markdown-page-generator-plugin` (a Maven `flexmark-java` plugin) _is not required with Doxia 1.8_. See [current doxia modules](https://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia/). Although, `markdown-page-generator-plugin` does remain an option for working with markdown content outside the context of Doxia.

Comment: @l-marc-l I suspected that, but didn't find the way to enable the rewrite link option in doxia-module-markdown. After your comment, I'll check a little bit more. Thank you!

Comment: @l-marc-l I checked and still couldn't find it. It looks to me that link rewrite is achieved in `flexmark-java` implementing `com.vladsch.flexmark.html.LinkResolver`. markdown-page-generator seems to do this in [FlexmarkLinkResolver.java](https://github.com/walokra/markdown-page-generator-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ruleoftech/markdown/page/generator/plugin/FlexmarkLinkResolver.java), but I cannot find this interface implemented in [doxia-module-markdown source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-doxia/tree/doxia-1.8/doxia-modules/doxia-module-markdown).

Comment: @l-marc-l I've added this issue to doxia project to request this new feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DOXIA-584

Comment: @jmones based on your observation & jira issue, i added a caveat to the answer that  Doxia's use of `flexmark-java` may not provide access to all `flexmark-java` features. thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your files on a server and you have access to your website directory, you could try using the `.htaccess` file that should be at the root of the directory where your MD files are in.

In `.htaccess`, add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*).md /$1.html
```

If you know a bit of Regex, you will notice that the `RewriteRule` is capturing the name of your `.md` file and converting it to a `.html`. This works with **all** requests of `.md` files, and does not edit anything in GitHub or the distant server.
For more details, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297530/i-want-to-rewrite-an-url-on-my-site-what-can-i-do/) on how to rewrite URLs using `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to get the markdown translator to do it, because it better understands the difference between `.md` in github /blob links and those in relative links.   I've already got something hacky like this in perl but it's less than ideal.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Uh-huh. However `.htaccess` will leave every files untouched, thus not affecting external links (i.e those pointing to github from the site)